# Databricks - How to check if a delta table exists or not (using table identifier, NOT path )

Tags: delta-lake, databricks-unity-catalog, gcp-databricks

Is there any delta methods or attributes (In Python/Scala APIs) that are helpful in finding out if a given table name is present in a given schema or not?

I came across this method `isDeltaTable()` of this class `delta.tables.DeltaTable`, which will return *true* if the provided table path is a delta table and *false* if it is not a delta table. But, is there any other method that accepts **identifier(table name)** instead of **table path**, since in UC catalog, the table are managed internally by databricks (and we can't always provide the exact path of managed tables).

Answer (score 0):

Try [`DeltaTable.forName()`](https://docs.delta.io/0.7.0/api/python/index.html#delta.tables.DeltaTable.forName).
According to the documentation it receives as parameter the name of the table or view.